# Creating a new Command using Artisan, without shell access

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I need to set some `cron` jobs on a *Laravel* website. It seems that first I have to run the following command in the shell to begin with it:

```
php artisan command:make CustomCommand
```

However since I don't have shell access, my only other option is to use `Artisan::call` and access is it over HTTP. The syntax is something like this:

```
\Artisan::call( 'command:make', 
    array(
        'arg-name' => 'CustomCommand',
        '--option' => ''
    )
);
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I can't seem to find the `arg-name` value for the `command:make` command.

I really appreciate if someone mention the *Argument Name* for the `make` command or suggest an alternative solution that doesn't need shell access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this manually by creating a class that represents your command. The cli command generates next file :

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

class Test extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'command:name';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command arguments.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return array(
            array('example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'An example argument.'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the console command options.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            array('example', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'An example option.', null),
        );
    }

}
```

put it in your `commands` directory (for L4 it's `app/commands`). Next simply add to your `app/start/artisan.php` file the binding for your custom command :

`Artisan::add(new Test);`
and that's it. This is the ideal solution when you don't need to touch your server's crontab. In case you have access to it from CP it would be the simplest solution. In case you don't have such ability, there would be now way to set the crontab to run your custom command. Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers! Haven't tested yet but I'm pretty sure it will work. Thanks!

Comment: Great, give it a try, and post yor success back :)

Comment: BTW, what should be the file name? `MyCommand.php` or `myCommand.php`?

Comment: Or does it matter at all?

Comment: I think it should be the same as the class name.